# Why does the path // exists?

Tags: filesystem

I have on occasion accidentally typed this to change to the root directory.

```
$ cd //
```

It works fine and I am in the root directory because `ls` returns same results as if I am on root. But why is this even valid ?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file, http://superuser.com/questions/389338/which-directory-does-path-represent-in-linux, http://superuser.com/questions/584234/difference-between-and-directories-in-bash-osx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many slashes as you want after each other at any position. It doesn't change anything.

You also can add ./ as often as you want because "." is the link from every directory to itself.

This and other acrobatics even work when you're saving files. I often will save files with names like "/tmp/a.png". The last time was about 4 minutes ago.

Try it with the address bar of your browser on any page. Same thing.

Comment: ``http://askubuntu.com////////questions/604562/why-does-the-path-exists/`` gave me a HTTP 404

Comment: Ooops. There is this thing where URLs like this are chopped apart and put together to something like `http://askubuntu.com/usercontent/questions.php?id=604562`. It probably doesn't work with that. Anyway: It works on your terminal. ;-)

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it accordingly.